# Why $\det(A-λI)$ can be written as a polynomial about $λ$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I know this is one of the definitions of eigenvalue. But how can I prove this with only the definition: $$Ax = λx$$?

I am a beginner of LA, so this question may seem stupid. Thank you guys.

Comment: The deinition is not only $Ax=\lambda x$, but there's the condition that $x\ne 0$. In termes of coordinates, you have  homogeneous linear system which must have a *non-trivial* solution, and this is characterised by the condition $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix,$$\det(A-\lambda I)=\sum_\sigma\prod_{i=1}^n(A-\lambda I)_{i\sigma(i)},$$where $\sum_\sigma$ sums over all permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,\,\cdots,\,n\}$. In terms of the Kronecker delta, $(A-\lambda I)_{ij}=A_{ij}-\delta_{ij}\lambda$. Each of the above products is then a polynomial in $\lambda$, as is the sum.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is the composition of two polynomial functions: $\lambda\mapsto A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}$ and $\det$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the definition of the determinant of a square matrix $(a_{ij}),$ which is always a type of homogeneous polynomial of its entries $a_{ij}.$

For the matrix $A-\lambda I,$ where $A$ is a given square matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix of same order, we see that all the entries are numbers, except for those involving the unknown $\lambda.$ It is therefore not surprising that this is a polynomial in $\lambda.$